# use implicit to find "One" element of HList typeclass to inject

Tags: scala, shapeless

Here is the code:

```
    trait Service[T<: HList] {
      def doStuff(): Unit
    }

    class A
    class B
    class C

    class ServiceAB extends Service[A :: B :: HNil] {
      override def doStuff(): Unit = println("handling a b")
    }

    class ServiceC extends Service[C :: HNil] {
      override def doStuff(): Unit = println("handling c")
    }

    implicit val serviceAB = new ServiceAB
    implicit val serviceC = new ServiceC

    def operate[T, W <: HList](x: T)(implicit service: Service[W]) = {
      service.doStuff()
    }

    operate(new C)
```

I just wonder is it possible or what should I code in the type level to inject implicit serviceC when operate(new C) is executed, since class C is the element of HList of type class of ServiceC ?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realy don't know why you need this :)

So your code works, but if you pass type parameter explicitly:

```
operate[C, C :: HNil](new C)
```

If you want same, but implicitly, you can define your class type:

```
trait Service[L <: HList, U] { def doStuff(): Unit }

trait lowPriority {
  implicit def otherwise[L <: HList, U] =
    new Service[L, U] {
      def doStuff(): Unit = println("handling otherwise")
    }
}

object Service extends lowPriority {
  implicit def ab[L <: HList, U]
  (implicit e: L =:= (A :: B :: HNil), 
            s: Selector[L, U]) =
    new Service[L, U] {
      def doStuff(): Unit = println("handling a b")
    }

  implicit def c[L <: HList, U]
  (implicit e: L =:= (C :: HNil), 
            s: Selector[L, U]) =
    new Service[L, U] {
      def doStuff(): Unit = println("handling c")
    }
  }
}

def operate[T, W <: HList](x: T)(implicit service: Service[W, T]) = {
  service.doStuff()
}
```

So this works as expected:

```
operate(new C) //> handling c
operate(new A) //> handling a b
operate(new B) //> handling a b
```

It is possible to make it more general (so it will check is type you need is in a `HList`, ohterwise if it doesn't) (using Curry-Howard isomorphism, great article with explanations by Miles Sabin: http://www.chuusai.com/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/):

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._

type ¬[A] = A => Nothing
type ∨[T, U] = ¬[¬[T] with ¬[U]]
type ¬¬[A] = ¬[¬[A]]

class A
class B
class C
class D //> additional class for example

trait Service[L <: HList, U] { def doStuff(): Unit }

trait lowPriority {
  implicit def otherwise[L <: HList, U] =
    new Service[L, U] {
      def doStuff(): Unit = println("handling otherwise")
    }
}

object Service extends lowPriority {
  implicit def ab[L <: HList, U]
  (implicit e: (¬¬[U] <:< (A ∨ B)), 
            s: Selector[L, TypeTag[U]]) =
    new Service[L, U] {
      def doStuff(): Unit = println("handling a b")
    }

  implicit def c[L <: HList, U](implicit e: U =:= C, s: Selector[L, TypeTag[U]]) =
    new Service[L, U] {
      def doStuff(): Unit = println("handling c")
    }
  }
}

def operateBi[T, W <: HList](x: T, w: W)(implicit service: Service[W, T]) = {
  service.doStuff()
}
```

Defining `HLists` of types:

```
val hl1 = implicitly[TypeTag[A]] :: implicitly[TypeTag[B]] :: HNil
val hl2 = implicitly[TypeTag[C]] :: HNil

operateBi(new C, hl1)
operateBi(new A, hl2)
operateBi(new B, hl1)
operateBi(new D, hl1)
```

Works as expected.